# Don't show the "protect" link for questions that are locked

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

In questions that are already locked, the link to protect it should not be shown, as it is not  possible to answer the question.

In [Favourite untranslatables](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205/favourite-untranslatables), which is locked, I can see the "protect" link.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If all in a sudden you see two mouse pointers, nothing is wrong. My mouse pointer insisted to be in the screenshot, and I had to make it happy.

Comment: This will be deployed tonight.